# Can't read grpc response in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, grpc

I have a grpc server written in Go that works ok.
rpc: `Send (stream FromClientMessage) returns (stream FromServerMessage)`

When I use a Unity3d client, I can send a message:

`_requestStream.WriteAsync(new FromClientMessage {});`

It works ok - server receives it. Now the server sends a message.

For receiving it in Unity client, I use sample code from the tutorial:

```
Task.Run(async() =>
{
   var stream = _client.Send().ResponseStream;
   while (await stream.MoveNext())
   {
      Debug.Log("received something");
   }
}
```

However the debug message is never printed. Debugger shows that the execution suspends on `MoveNext()`

What's the proper way to receive grpc messages from a stream in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the solution from the question is that method for getting streams from the client is not a normal accessor. Response stream seems to be paired with request stream for each getter call. So the code above should be (**only one call to _client.Send()** ):

```
AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<FromClientMessage, FromServerMessage> duplexStream = _client.Send();

Task.Run(async() =>
{
   var stream = duplexStream.ResponseStream;
   while (await stream.MoveNext())
   {
      Debug.Log("received something");
   }
}
duplexStream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new FromClientMessage{});
```